# why am i getting undefined when returning a value

Tags: javascript, node.js

so I keep getting undifinded when trying to get just one number to return. what am I doing wrong?

```
const megaball = () => {

  let random_number
  while (true) {
    random_number = math.floor(math.random() * 100)
    console.log(random_number)
    if (random_number <= 25 && random_number !== 0) {
      console.log('break')
      break
    }
  }
  return random_number
}
```

the results from this function are as follows:

```
55
67
17
break
17
undefined
PS C:\Users\dalla\OneDrive\Documents\lottery>
```

I need to know why I am getting undefined when i am suppose to be just returning the 17 as the random number.

Comment: Your code does NOT produce the result you claim. The fact that you use `math` instead of `Math` suggests that the code you ACTUALLY have is not the same as the code you presented in the question - correction:, if you do `console.log(megaball())` then you get what you claim - since `console.log` function does return `undefined` - perhaps you should mention you are executing this using node REPL

Answer (score 1):

Make sure when you test this function, you are correctly capturing and logging the return value with console.log(result); after you call megaball();. If you're directly calling megaball(); in the console without logging its return value, the console will show the last console.log() output from the function (which might be 'break' or the last random number generated) and then possibly show undefined if the function call itself isn't part of an expression being logged. This is a common behavior in many JavaScript environments, including Node.js and browser consoles, where an expression that doesn't explicitly return a value will result in undefined being output in the console.

Comment: Also JavaScript is case-sensitive, and the correct object for mathematical operations is Math (with an uppercase "M"), not math. So, you should use Math.floor() and Math.random().

Comment: So I do not have a car called return but when I call the function the result is 17 then undefined